# How can add checkboxes to dynamically-created list items?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make the "li" created using JavaScript checkboxes?
I've tried some methods but nothing.

```js
function addLi () {
    var x = document.createElement("LI");
    var t = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('text').value);
    x.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("elements").appendChild(x);
    return false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <lang>
        <title>ToDoList</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="todolist.js"></script>
    <head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form onSubmit="return addLi();">
                <input type="text" value="Type here!" id="text">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>

            <ul id="elements">

            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to make a to do list and I want, when I check one of them to automatically be deleted

Comment: Checkboxes are useful to represent a boolean state (true/false) ; here this would correspond to your li's existence right? unchecked it exists, checked it does not. Except the problem is that you will never see the checked state since the li won't exist anymore. I think a button would be more appropriate here, that you could style as a checkbox if you want

Comment: Aaron, the OP's example appears to be a to-do list and the check is probably whether or not it's been completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be what you're trying to do?

```js
function addLi () {
    var x = document.createElement("LI");

    var c = document.createElement("INPUT");
    c.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    x.appendChild(c);

    var t = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('text').value);
    x.appendChild(t);
    
    document.getElementById("elements").appendChild(x);
    return false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <lang>
        <title>ToDoList</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="todolist.js"></script>
    <head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form onSubmit="return addLi();">
                <input type="text" value="Type here!" id="text">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>

            <ul id="elements">

            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just append an `input` element to the `li`:

```
function addLi () {
    var li = document.createElement("LI");
    var tn = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('text').value);
    var cb = document.createElement("input");
    cb.type = "checkbox";

    li.appendChild(cb);
    li.appendChild(tn);
    document.getElementById("elements").appendChild(li);

    return false;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z46kuntv/)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add another `<input type="checkbox">` as your `li`'s children.

```
function addLi () {
    var x = document.createElement("LI");
    var t = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('text').value);
    var i = document.createElement("INPUT");
    i.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    x.appendChild(t);
    x.appendChild(i);
    document.getElementById("elements").appendChild(x);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
function addLi () {
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.name = "name";
    checkbox.value = "value";
    checkbox.id = "id";

    var x = document.createElement("LI");
    x.appendChild(checkbox);

    document.getElementById("elements").appendChild(x);
    return false;
}
```